# How can i read/get each message body text content and also the title of each message and from and to?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-api, gmail-api

What i mean is to get a List that will be build like this format:

from to message

For example in the List in the first index i will see:

From: Daniel To: Jhon Message: hello world

In this code i'm using now all i'm getting in the result variable is 1445 messages and that's strange in my gmail.com account i see i have 374 emails in the inbox so why the variable result return all the time 1445 ? I tried to change in the JSON file to my gmail account then to my friend gmail account in both cases it return 1445. How can i make that it will return the number of emails according to the gmail account in the JASON file ?

And inside in the result list variable for example on index 0 when i stand with the mouse on it all i can get is the message Id and the message ThreadId but how do i get the From and To and the Message body/text ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Google_Gmail
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Youtube Uploader";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ListMessages(GmailServices(), "me", "");


        }

        private GmailService GmailServices()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream(@"C:\jason file\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Gmail API service.
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            return service;
        }

        public static List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message> ListMessages(GmailService service, String userId, String query)
        {
            List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message> result = new List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message>();
            UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
            request.Q = query;

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
                    result.AddRange(response.Messages);
                    request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                }
            } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));

            return result;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not marked answer.

Answer (score 1):

> In my gmail.com account i see i have 374 emails in the inbox so why
>   the variable result return all the time 1445?

The `Users.Messages.List(userId)` will return the Id of all the messages you have in in your account, not just messages with the INBOX-label. Try the query `Q = "in:INBOX"`

> And inside in the result list variable for example on index 0 when i
>   stand with the mouse on it all i can get is the message Id and the
>   message ThreadId but how do i get the From and To and the Message
>   body/text?

The `Messages.List` will only give you the Id of the message and the thread it belongs to. You need to use the Messages.Get request with every Id to get the actual message.

Then, you have to look at the `From`-header, `To`-header and the `Body` of the message to get the information you need.

Comment: I changed the query string to: ListMessages(GmailServices(), "me", "in:INBOX"); now the variable result give me 1059 it's not as before 1445 but still not the amount of emails i see in my gmail account.

Comment: I tried now "in:inbox" lower case and also tried to change "me" to my gmail account: "myccount@gmail.com" in all cases it's giving back 1059 in the variable result.

Comment: Do you mean the number you see next to your `Inbox`-label in the Gmail Client? That is a counter of unread messages. Try `in:INBOX AND is:unread`

Comment: Doing as quesry in:INBOX AND is:unread give me 950 and if i changed the end of it from unread to read then 109. Yes i mean when in chrome i'm surfing to gmail.com into my account and on the left click on inbox i see 377 now.

Comment: I see now in the gmail.com web site that you can select Primary or Social or Promitions. So on Primary i have 463 emails on Social 331 and Promotions 200 maybe it's just a filter not sure. And on the left side i see in red color inbox(377)